# How can I customize setters in Spring Roo DBRE-generated entities?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-roo

This question may expose my lack of knowledge of AspectJ but here goes anyway :)

I have successfully used Spring Roo to Database Reverse Engineer a bunch of tables into a new Roo project. I'd like to be able to keep the round-trip-engineering aspect of Roo by not 'pushing' my aspects into plain old Java classes. However, I am experiencing an issue with assigning values to the member fields that are defined in the Aspect.

For example, I have a RooDbManaged entity class, let's call it X, and Roo has generated an aspect: X_Roo_DbManaged. Now, I want to customize a setter for the field 'updateDate' so that I can assign the date to be the current at the time of persistence. So, I have placed my custom code in the class X as follows:

```
 public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
    this.updateDate = new Date();
}
```

This causes Roo to remove the setter from the aspect, as I would expect, because I have now defined it in X.

This gives me an error: 
*The field X.updateDate is not visible*

If I change the visibility of the field in the X_Roo_DbManaged aspect to 'public' (something that I'd rather not do), this resolves the issue until Roo automatically regenerates the aspect causing the error to recur.

My guess is that I'm missing something so obvious that no one has thought it worthwhile posting, as my usually successful Googling failed to find any solution for this one!

I should add that my workaround is to customize the relevant methods from the X_Roo_Controller by moving them into the XController and assigning the date there using the unmodified setter. This seems to be counter intuitive as I would really like the updateDate always to be the current date when set. Interestingly the Roo-generated   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) annotation on the updateDate field does not provide this functionality. I'd realy like to be able to tell Roo with a Roo command that certain DBRE fields ought to have this behavior and not have to worry about what is essentially 'plumbing'.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` instead of hacking the setters

```
public class X {
   @PreUpdate
   public void beforeSaving() {
      this.setUpdateDate(new Date());
   }
}
```

Otherwise you can still put the field itself from `X_Roo_DbManaged.aj` into `X.java` file, but you will loose the ability to incrementally reverse engineer that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the field updateDate into X.java for it to be visible.